# I have error in app level build.gradle file

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, build.gradle

I have error on this line of code in my build.gradle in app level directory or android/app/build.gradle :

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "co.appbrewery.clima"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {

}
```

As you can see, i have an error on the `Property function` and `FileNotFoundException function`.

Here is what the `Property function` error say:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'Properties'
```

And here is what the error say about `FileNotFoundException function`:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'FileNotFoundException'
```

Below is my ss of my error and my file structure:

[image]

My code is actually from the Angela Yu Flutter course on Github as i participate in her course. When i copy the file, the error already appear. How to solve this problem? Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: can you share ss of project structure of android module?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention above that this build.gradle is inside of the app level folder. Amdroid/app/build.gradle